# AS3 physical path problem in linux environment

Tags: actionscript-3

Am developing a video player in as3 , everything is fine, but finally i got a prob in basic itself.

Question is How to specify the path to loading xml into flash. FOr example

urlreq.load("hostname/filename");

instead of host name i have to specify my physical path infact i should. so how to specify this.

means i have to load a xml file from root directory, something like

"/opt/adobe/fms/applications/vod/media/moviename/chapters.xml"

here i couldnot get the file.

Please some one help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but as far as I know there is no way to specify an absolute path for the filesystem; When using an absolute path (/...) it is actually relative to the root URL of the web-site where this SWF is being served from (or the folder where it is being run from during debug process).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Cameron, yes thats the problem am facing. Because i have to load the chapters list and saub title list from the streaming path itself. or else i should have those names in db and have to store all thos under web directory then it will work. but it is like loop through concept. so i need some other way.